# i need some Telephone Input Plugins for Js

Tags: javascript, input, plugins, required

Telephone Input Plugins required of JavaScript

i have searched and got these results

1. https://intl-tel-input.com/
2. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/telify/cioaocgapbjhdiodcabjlnihjfbopafb?hl=en
3. http://www.abstractcrm.com/
   4)https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html

But these does not fulfil my requirements so can anyone provide me more Telephone Input Plugins of JavaScript

Comment: And what is your requirement?

Comment: need more similar plugins